# Problem with RDPSND.DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, remote-desktop

I have an application in Visual Basic, using .NET Framework 2.0. This application is run at the client site on thin clients using Windows Terminal Services. It is a sort of Point-Of-Sale, and makes a sound when a item is successfuly scanned.

In remote desktop, we have enabled sound to be carried to the local computer.

It has been working fine till now, but has developed a snag for last few days. After a few lines are scanned (never after a fixed number of lines) - the application crashes.

Upon examination of event viewer I found the following:

Faulting application bonepose.exe, version 2.0.0.0, stamp 4a683010, faulting module rdpsnd.dll, version 5.2.3790.0, stamp 3e8024be, debug? 0, fault address 0x000029d5.

After this, I tried running the application without the sound and it worked.

How can I fix this problem? Any ideas?

PS: After crash, if we restart the application, it become really slow. It takes almost 30 seconds to scan a line - where it otherwise takes less than a second.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a weird case similar to this one, and I wanted to share it just in case it may help (although this is an old post):


The symptons were:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/329819/freelibrary-in-the-winmm-dlls-module-initialization-routine-causes-access-violation

In my case, the source of the problem was due to mixing managed DLLs with unmanaged code. To solve this problem, I changed the order used for the input LIBs in the link section (managed ones at the begining), and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the audio driver is ornery. Update the audio driver. Alternatively disable the audio on the box, or remove your app's audio code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are all the service packs installed on your machine? Which OS BTW?
2. Can you try and replace the file with a build in Winodws Sound? Does it still happens?
3. Which API to play the sound are you using?